# not getting option to create Scala Object in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-oxygen

I am not getting the option to create Scala Object in Eclipse project. I see the Scala nature is already added but still the issue is coming.

Note: This is an already existing project which I imported and I need to make some changes with it.

Kindly let me know if any additional information is required.

[image]

Comment: The **ScalaIDE** for **Eclipse** was already deprecated and abandoned when I started to learn the language like 5 years ago. By now it is just ancient history; pick any other IDE / code editor of your preference. - BTW, in theory, you should be able to use [**Eclipse** thought **metals**](https://olafurpg.github.io/metals/docs/editors/eclipse.html). However, AFAIK, this project was also abandoned for lack of interest.

Comment: What is displayed in this menu depends on the active perspective. Please note, the tooling you use is several years old.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez The project which I am working has a UI and backend(Scala/Spark). I used to use Intellij but we dont have Ultimate edition to work on it. I tried to import the eclipse project to Intellij but there were issues which I am still working on